# ¿Cómo puedo moverme por la tabla ASCII saltandome un número por cada suma? C++

Tags: c++

Bien, esta es mi duda, estoy en mi proyecto, y para no hacerlo largo estoy moviendome por la tabla ASCII depende de la suma de valores(Ya que requiero imprimir las mismas) Soy novato, gracias a un usuario en un post anterior vi que podía moverme de esa manera en la tabla. Tal que, ahora necesito moverme en la misma, esta siendo Repetida en una secuencia de la siguiente manera.

[image: TABLA]

¿Qué patron logré visualizar? Que los pares son minusculas, y los impares son mayusculas, por lo que me dispuse a verificar eso y moverme por la tabla ASCII, mas sin embargo, no me está acertando en los resultados que me salen en pantalla, y no se realmente que sea. Lo tengo como una función.

```
int Letras_Tracyectoria(int valor)
{
    char Back;
    if((valor % 2 == 0) and (valor < 26))
    {
        Back = static_cast<char>('a' + valor);
    }
    else{
        Back = static_cast<char>('A' + valor - 26);
    }
    return Back;
}
```

Y la misma no me está dando el resultado como debería. Apreciaría su ayuda, consejos y sugerencias para solventar el problema y mejorar. Gracias de antemano.

Buenos días, tardes, noches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SECUENCIA   minus  mayus
a = 0       a=0    A=1
A = 1       b=2    A=3
b = 2       c=4    C=5
B = 3       d=6    D=7
...         ...    ...
```

sacar la secuencia de las minúsculas parece fácil. Simplemente hay que dividir el valor entre 2:

```
char letra = static_cast<char>('a' + index/2);
```

las mayúsculas son igual de sencillas... de hecho la ecuación es la misma!!!

```
char letra = static_cast<char>('A' + index/2);
```

¿Cómo es eso de que la ecuación es la misma? Bueno, aquí nos estamos beneficiando de ciertas características de los números enteros (recordemos que un `char` no es más que un número de 1 byte). Resulta que los números enteros no pueden representar decimales, así que en el caso de una división los decimales simplemente desaparecen. Así:

```
A=1 => 1/2=0 => A+0=A
B=3 => 3/2=1 => A+1=B
C=5 => 5/2=2 => A+2=C
...
```

Así pues la función podría quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
char Letras_Tracyectoria(int valor)
{
    char Back;

    if( valor % 2 == 0 )
      Back = static_cast<char>('a' + valor/2);
    else
      Back = static_cast<char>('A' + valor/2);

    return Back;
}
```

O, también, si usamos el condicional ternario:

```
char Letras_Tracyectoria(int valor)
{
    return (valor % 2) ? static_cast<char>('A' + valor/2)
                       : static_cast<char>('a' + valor/2);
}
```

O, repitiendo menos código:

```
char Letras_Tracyectoria(int valor)
{
    return static_cast<char>(((valor % 2) ? 'A' : 'a') + valor/2);
}
```

Comment: Gracias Eferion, las dos publicaciones me las has respondido y me has sacado de dudas, de verdad aprecio eso. <3

Comment: Otra cosita, estoy viendo sobre los operadores ternarios pero ¿Técnicamente no se debió colocar de igual manera (valor % 2 == 0)? Si pudieras aclararme esa duda, estaría agradecido.

Comment: @RoderickGuacuto si te fijas, con el operador ternario he invertido el calculo de minúsculas y minúsculas. Si `valor` es impar, `valor%2==1`, y este valor, al ser distinto de cero, devolverá `true` en una operación booleana... y cuando estamos ante un número impar tenemos que convertir a mayúsculas. Cuando `valor` sea par, `valor%2==0`, que al convertirse a booleano resultará en `false`

Comment: Ohh vale vale, ya lo he visto. De verdad, muchas gracias.